# Discontinuity of second kind On R

Tags: real-analysis

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2+1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ x & x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}.$ Prove that $f$ has discontinuity of second kind at every point $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you define this term? Can you present your attempts?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to proceed if the given function is defined on Q and R-Q. I saw in many books, they use to disprove it's continuity using sequential criteria of continuous function... Plz help me..

Comment: Can we proceed like that? Let c€R, and consider a seq {x_n} of rational number converging to c. Then lim f(x_n)=lim [ (x_n)²+1]=c²+1.  Again, take a seq {y_n} of irrational number converging to c. Then lim[f(y_n)]= lim y_n =c.  And c≠c²+1. Hence limit doesn't exist at any points of R. Hence a discontinuity of Second Kind.

Comment: Yep, that's right. The only thing to be careful of is proving that $c$ is never equal to $c^2+1$.

Comment: Well...Thank You...Sir